# Query document with a particular value in array of objects

Tags: json, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I'm having a series of documents in cosmos DB where the structure is as follows:

```
{
    "id" : "s2912vdla"
    "allowed-usrs": [
        {
            "id": "myId"
        }
    ],
    ....
}
```

I need to be able to get all the documents, which has the id `myId` in `allowed-usrs.id`.

Unfortunately, its unclear for me how the SQL Cosmos API would achieve this - I've read in the docs that I should use the `IN` clause, but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
SELECT * FROM c IN t.allowed-usrs WHERE c.id = "myId"
```

Comment: what is the expected outcome?

Comment: the entire document(s) that contains `myId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```sql
SELECT VALUE c --because we have JOIN we can't use *
FROM c --we need c because we want to return the full object
JOIN a IN c['allowed-usrs'] --brackets required because the char '-' is not allowed
WHERE a.id = 'myId'
```

or maybe more correctly for your use the query below. The first query will yield duplicate items if `myId` appears multiple times in the allowed user list (because to the `JOIN`), while the below only yields one.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c['allowed-usrs'], { 'id': 'myId' }, true)
--looks for a partial match in the allowed user array
```

Comment: @JeppeChristensen added a query that's probably better for your context.